# How do we directly read a file from ".bin" by avoiding looping as below

Tags: ios, c, binaryfiles

I am trying to fetch a file from binary data which has about 4700 files. How do i directly point a specific file avoiding loop(while) as below.

It is taking good amount of time for me to read files which are at index 3000+

I am going through a while iteration where filename is being compared for each iteration. If File name is matching then i am trying to read the uncompressed data and saving to documents directory.

Could any one suggest me a way to deal with this.

```
struct FILE_DATA buffer;

FILE *myFile = fopen(binaryPath, "rb");

f_name = f_name.lowercaseString;

const char * fileNameChar = f_name.UTF8String;



if (myFile == NULL)
{
    fputs("File error", stderr);
    completionhandler(false,@"");
}

// Go to where the file count spec is: byte 12
fseek(myFile, 12, SEEK_SET);

// Should be a sizeof 40.
int temp = sizeof(buffer);

// Get the Table Offset.
uint32_t loc;
fread(&loc, 4, 1, myFile);
rewind(myFile);
// Go to the beginning of the file tables.
fseek(myFile, loc, SEEK_SET);

// Variable to store where the chart archive will be.
uint32_t loc2 = 0;

int _fileFound = 0;
// Copy the file into the buffer:
while(fread(&buffer,1, temp, myFile) != 0)
{
    // Reads the next 40 bytes into the struct.
        DebugLog("Buffer Name : %s == ",buffer.name);

        // If the names are a match, then mark the location.

        if(strcmp(buffer.name, fileNameChar) == 0)
        {
            _fileFound = 1;
            loc2 = buffer.offset;
            break;
        }
}

if(_fileFound == 0)
{
    // Alert if the file was not found.
    fputs("File Not Found", stderr);
    completionhandler(false,@"");

}

// Navigate to the location of the file.

fseek(myFile, loc2, SEEK_SET);

uLongf unCompSize = buffer.size_d;
uLongf compSize = buffer.size_c;

char  *rawDataBuff = malloc(buffer.size_c);
//allocate buffer to hold the compressed TCL file

char  *  unCompDataBuff = malloc(buffer.size_d);

//allocate buffer to hold the decompressed TCL file
if (rawDataBuff == NULL){
    fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
    completionhandler(false,@"");

}


fread(rawDataBuff,buffer.size_c, 1,myFile);

//read in compress TCL file into the buffer
int z_result = uncompress((Bytef*)unCompDataBuff, &unCompSize, (const Bytef*)rawDataBuff, compSize);

DebugLog("status %d",z_result);
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with iOS?

Comment: it has nothing to with iOS. But i am trying to read .".bin" this in an iOS app